# ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) on line 6

Tags: php, mysql

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) on line 6

the error is from line 6 where display block is i have removed the spaces from it and even closed it. the code still wont run then when i removed the ; the whole code goes yellow. 
i have another code that has the same error to and tried removing the(<<) but nothing closed it still the same thing. the only time it reads past this is when i remove the ;. but the whole code after that line turns yellow

```
 <?php
include 'ch19_include.php';
if (!$_POST) {
  //haven't seen the form, so display it
  $display_block = <<<END_OF_BLOCK;
  <form method="POST" action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]">;

  <p><label for="subject">Subject:</label><br/>
  <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" size="40" /></p>

 <p><label for="message">Mail Body:</label><br/>
 <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="50"   rows="10"> </textarea></p>
 <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
END_OF_BLOCK;
```

Comment: could you provide a more complete code sample? for example: where does your heredoc end? (don't post it in a comment; edit your question instead)

Comment: and what exactly do you mean by **the code turns yellow**? do you mean, by any chance, your editors syntax highlighting for heredoc-strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$display_block = <<<END_OF_BLOCK
(your text)
END_OF_BLOCK;
```

remove the semicolon after the first END_OF_BLOCK.
the "code turning yellow" is just your editor telling you it *knows* this piece of code is a heredoc-string. nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

You have to end your heredoc somewhere else. Example:

```
<?php
include 'ch19_include.php';
if (!$_POST) {

$display_block = <<<END_OF_BLOCK
<form method="POST" action="$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]">;
//more code
END_OF_BLOCK;
```

Comment: did you remove the semicolom just of this line too?
$display_block = <<<END_OF_BLOCK;